# Metabase is not working (starting) with MySQL

Tags: mysql, metabase

I read the documentation about [running metabase with docker from here](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-metabase-on-docker.html) and [setting metabase up with mysql from here](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/configuring-application-database.html) and followed all the instruction as per the documentation.

Here is the docker-compose.yml file I used to run metabase:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:v0.39.1
    environment:
      - MB_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - MB_DB_DBNAME=metabase
      - MB_DB_PORT=3306
      - MB_DB_USER=secretuser
      - MB_DB_PASS=secretword
      - MB_DB_HOST=secrethost
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error.

```
metabase_1  | 2021-05-17 08:27:59,084 ERROR metabase.core :: Metabase Initialization FAILED
metabase_1  | liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set migrations/000_migrations.yaml::1::agilliland:
metabase_1  |      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=32027) Table 'core_organization' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE `metabase`.`core_organization` (`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, `slug` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, `description` TEXT NULL, `logo_url` VARCHAR(254) NULL, `inherits` BIT(1) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `PK_CORE_ORGANIZATION` PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE (`slug`)) ENGINE InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci]
metabase_1  |   at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637)
..
..
metabase_1  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'core_organization' already exists
metabase_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1688)
metabase_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1550)
metabase_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1513)
metabase_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:256)
metabase_1  |   ... 57 more
metabase_1  | 2021-05-17 08:27:59,109 INFO metabase.core :: Metabase Shutting Down ...
```

I also tried to run directly without using compose file using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e "MB_DB_TYPE=mysql" -e "MB_DB_DBNAME=metabase" \
-e "MB_DB_PORT=3306" -e "MB_DB_USER=secretuser" -e 'MB_DB_PASS=secretpass' \
-e "MB_DB_HOST=secrethost" --name metabase metabase/metabase:v0.39.1
```

I get the exactly same error as with the compose file.

On further searches I found a [similar issue in github](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/2672) stating that "Table 'core_organization' already exists", however, they claim that it is already fixed but I'm still having the issue. In the issue page they suggest: `java -jar metabase.jar migrate force`. **How can I run this from docker ?**

NOTE: I have tried to drop all the table and start with fresh schema multiple times and it didn't work as well.

NOTE: the database I use is AWS RDS, just to make sure that it's not related with AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was that I didn't have permissions to ALTER and REFERENCE in AWS RDS. Once I got those permissions everything worked fine.